# Playing video only when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, html5-video

I am trying to play video only when the play button is clicked, using jQuery `attr` but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a example. I want the video to have sound and play ONLY when button is pressed as i have another button linked to another video. Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/vgmaxK) and my code is following,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".glyphicon-play-circle").click(function() {
    jQuery(".sports-video").css("display", "block")
    jQuery("#bgvid").toggleClass("is-not-active");   
    jQuery(".fullscreen").toggleClass("is-video-active").attr("autoplay","true");

});
```

});

Comment: For a start you can remove autoplay attribute from the video tag

Answer (score 4):

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJoMeV)

remove the `autoplay` attribute in the `<video>`.

To start the video do following in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".glyphicon-play-circle").click(function() {
        $('video').get(0).play();
    });
});
```

If you want to play several videos on your website you should give the video a class and select the class direct instead of `$('video')`

Comment: Great, this work! i see `get()` get the list of array passed into it, Does it depend of the structure of html or how it select the element based on array?

Comment: It is not part of this post, but how can i add a close button to the video like `glyphicon glyphicon-remove`, that close the window.

Comment: It's because play() is not a JQuery function. It's a function of the video (DOM) Element. That's why you have to select the nativ DOM-Element with get(0). Hope that helps :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "close the window". Close the whole browser window/tab or remove the <video>-Element?

Comment: Close the .fullscreen div, that is playing the video.

Comment: right now you have 2 videos in your HTML. The fullscreen div is not even the one you see because it's set to "display: none". You should remove the first video in your html and leave the one inside the .fullscreen div. The JQuery stays the same. Set .fullscreen to "display: block" (or just remove the "display:none"). To remove an element you can just do: $('.fullscreen').remove();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133908/discussion-between-nofel-and-daniel).

Comment: I have created new [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841065/video-wont-play-after-first-time-playing)